# Saving to two locations

Tags: vba, windows-10, synchronization, ms-project

I have Project 2016 on a Microsoft Surface pro 3 with the full version of Windows 10 and Office 365.

I followed instructions from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-project/can-you-set-up-a-ms-project-file-to-automatically/68847860-3c47-49d5-a4a8-06124dd63196. It is based on an older version of Project.

It saves to the second location, but crashes every time and does not save the original copy.

I did not change the code except for the file location. I did rename flag20 to yes (is that all I need to do is rename it?)

It crashes on this line

```
FileCloseEx Save:=pjDoNotSave, noauto:=True
```

This is the program:

```vb
Private Sub project_beforesave(ByVal pj As Project)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = False Then
        ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = True
        ActiveProject.SaveAs Name:="c:\users\John\desktop\backuptest.mpp"
        FileCloseEx Save:=pjDoNotSave, noauto:=True 'Crashes here
    Else
        ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

We use a tablet on construction job sites for the superintendent to update the job schedule in Project. Previously, all files were saved to the server and he would access them via VPN. Project opens files very slowly over VPN even though the file is very small. Even with a good 4g connection or wifi.

I have been trying to find a way to keep the files on the tablet but sync them with the server immediately when saved.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your line:

```
FileCloseEx Save:=pjDoNotSave, noauto:=True
```

with:

```
prjApp.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave, True
```

After you declare a variable and set is as a `New MsProject,Application`

The code below worked with the tests I've done on my PC:

```
Private Sub Project_BeforeClose(ByVal pj As Project)

Dim prjApp          As MSProject.Application
Set prjApp = New MSProject.Application

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = False Then
    ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = True
    ActiveProject.SaveAs Name:="c:\users\John\desktop\backuptest.mpp"
    prjApp.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave, True
Else
    ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Flag20 = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! looks like this is working well. For anyone who is needing to do the same thing as this... The only problem is that saving across VPN is very connected reliant. With a bad signal, it will sit there and save for a good while. with a great signal, it only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Well, now the problem we are running in to is that they are closing the file after messing something up and assuming it did not save because that didn't hit save. It didn't save on their tablet, but it did save to our server. Having this as a BeforeClose event is the problem. I should work fine if we can make it a BeforeSave event that will function properly.